# Page jumps when menu gets sticky on scrolling down

Tags: css, scroll, menu, sticky

I am working on one HTML theme. I have an issue with the sticky menu. When scrolling down on the page, Page content jumps up as the header is removed from the natural flow of the page.

I tried by giving margin-top to the main content of the site and it worked. But as I am working on a template, this solution is not useful for me. Any jQuery code would work fine. Thanks for the help in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sticky = $('.header-sticky');
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) sticky.addClass('header-sticky-on');
    else sticky.removeClass('header-sticky-on');
});
```

```css
header {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 99;
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        
/* Sticky header */ 
        header.header-sticky-on {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1000;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            -webkit-animation: fadeInDown .5s;
            animation: fadeInDown .5s;
            width: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(83, 88, 93, 0.1); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header-sticky">
     <!-- ======================= 
     Main header Start-->
     <nav class="main-header">
      <div class="container">
       "Content goes here Content goes here Content goes here"
      </div>
     </nav>
     <!-- ======================= 
     Main header End-->
</header>

<section class="main-content">
<p>
What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Why do we use it?

It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

Where does it come from?

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
Where can I get some?

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well? It's hard to diagnose your styling issues with just a couple CSS selectors

Comment: @tshimkus I have added my code. Can you please check now? Thanks!

Comment: I converted your code sample to an executable code snippet sample, but it doesn't look like there is enough to go off. Can you include more of your code?

Comment: @tshimkus Yes sure. Could you please review that now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is add padding-top to the `<body>` element. So when your sticky header becomes sticky it won't leave a gap between your content and the main wrapper.

This will stop it from jumping around but keeps the flexibility to make your theme.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var sticky = $('.header-sticky');
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  /* Added body padding when actived */
  if (scroll >= 100) {
    sticky.addClass('header-sticky-on');
    $('body').addClass('js-sticky-on');
  } else {
    sticky.removeClass('header-sticky-on');
    $('body').removeClass('js-sticky-on');
  }
});
```

```css
/* added: height of element */
body.js-sticky-on {
  padding-top: 18px;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

header.header-sticky-on {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown .5s;
  animation: fadeInDown .5s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(83, 88, 93, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header class="header-sticky">
    <!-- ======================= 
     Main header Start-->
    <nav class="main-header">
      <div class="container">
        "Content goes here Content goes here Content goes here"
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- ======================= 
     Main header End-->
  </header>

  <section class="main-content">
    <p>
      What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The
      point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
      Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where
      does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
      in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
      1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
      comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact
      original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour,
      or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend
      to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The
      generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but as I am making a reusable template, I fear I can not go with this as a viable solution. Do you have any other way to solve this? I mean without applying margin or padding? Thanks for the help Dude!

Comment: Too be honest, any solution you think of needs a way to fill in the blank left behind. Using the body tag (first html tag visible) is quite common. The only other way is to make a container. Give it a fixed height and make your header inside the container. When you make your header fixed. The container will be left behind assuring it won't jump. But still it's the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I realized that this is absolutely correct! Instead of applying margin/padding, I managed to add blank div after header when scrolled, same height as header. And it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm thankful that it worked! But too be honest it seems like the exact same thing as adding padding to the body-tag. :-) It doesn't matter how you fill up the space. Could you accept my answer?